# filtering pandas df with dcc.Dropdown and displaying the result in front end

Tags: dashboard, plotly-dash

I have a data frame like this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 4], 'col2': ["B", "A", "B"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I couldn't find a simple way to use `dcc.Dropdown` to filter the `df` for `col2` (options A or B in drop down) and display the filtered df in the front end. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's several questions all wrapped up together here, but the basic idea will be to build the dropdown with `options` based on the unique `col2` values. Then you'll need a callback that listens to the dropdown's `value` and uses that to index the dataframe with something like `df[df['col2'] == dropdown_value]` where `dropdown_value` is the arg in the callback.